# how to check / uncheck all checkboxes using single checkbox using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webusercontrol

I have 11 asp.net checkboxes in my asp.net webusercontrol ..

i want when checkbox1 is check thenrest of all checkboxes will be checked and if checkbox is uncheck then rest of all checkboxes will be unchecked how to do it if all my checkboxes are inside webusercontrol panel1.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally recommend using jQuery (or plain Javascript) for solving a problem like that. Add a common CSS class to the checkboxes you want to group/toggle.

```
$("input[type=checkbox].yourCssClass").each(function() {   
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

Comment: i want to do this in asp.net webuser control because all the controls are inside webusercontrol in inside panel1

Comment: jakob m the basic devloper socan u please provide me how to do it inside web user control ?

Comment: Add the same CSS class to all the checkboxes you want to toggle, and then use the jQuery function to check/uncheck them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jacob, jQuery would be the best solution.  This is messy to do on the server.

```
$('#mainCheckbox').click(
function(){
    $(.classforchildcheckboxes).attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
    }
```

)

Other check boxes just add the class='classforchildcheckboxes' during item databound.

Answer (score 0):

The other guys are right it is much easier to client side. But if you do need to this I would recommend putting the other 10 as CheckBoxList.

You can then mark the select all checkbox with AutoPostBack=True and 
then in the SelectAll_CheckedChanged method loop round each of the check box items

```
Sub SelectAll_CheckedChanged(byval sender as Object, byval e as CheckBoxEventArgs)
  For each chk in myCheckBoxList
      chk.checked = SelectAll.Checked
Next


End Sub
```

I don't have an IDE to verify this syntax is accurate but it should get you started